# Prevent join table being empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

### Relationships

```
class Promotion < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :promotion_sweepstakes,

  has_many :sweepstakes,
    :through => :promotion_sweepstakes
  end

class PromotionSweepstake < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :promotion
  belongs_to :sweepstake
end

class Sweepstake < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Not relevant in this question, but I included the class
end
```

So a Promotion has_many Sweepstake through join table PromotionSweepstake. This is a legacy db schema so the naming might seem a bit odd and there are some self.table_name == and foreign_key stuff left out.

The nature of this app **demands** that at least one entry in the join table is present for a promotionId, because not having a sweepstake would break the app.

### First question

How can I guarantee that there is always one entry in PromotionSweepstake for a Promotion? At least one Sweepstake.id has to be included upon creation, and once an entry in the join table is created there **has to be a minimum of one for each Promotion/promotion_id**.

### Second question (other option)

If the previous suggestion would not be possible, which I doubt is true, there's another way the problem can be worked around. There's a sort of "default Sweepstake" with a certain id. If through a form all the sweepstake_ids would be removed (so that all entries for the Promotion in the join table would be deleted), can I create a new entry in PromotionSweepstake?

#### pseudo_code (sort of)

delete promotion_sweepstake with ids [1, 4, 5] where promotion_id = 1
if promotion with id=1 has no promotion_sweepstakes
  add promotion_sweepstake with promotion_id 1 and sweepstake_id 100
end

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A presence validation should solve the problem in case of creation and modification of Promotions.

```
class Promotion < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :promotion_sweepstakes
  has_many :sweepstakes,
    :through => :promotion_sweepstakes
  validates :sweepstakes, :presence => true
end
```

In order to assure consistency when there's an attempt to delete or update a Sweepstake or a PromotionSweepstake you'd have to write your own validations for those two classes. They would have to check whether previously referenced Promotions are still valid, i.e. still have some Sweepstakes.

A simple solution would take and advantage of `validates :sweepstakes, :presence => true` in `Promotion`. After updating referenced PromotionSweepstakes or Sweepstakes in a transaction you would have to call `Promotion#valid?` on previously referenced Promotions. If they're not valid you roll back the transaction as the modification broke the consistency.

Alternatively you could use `before_destroy` in both PromotionSweepstake and Sweepstake in order to prevent changes violating your consistency requirements.

```
class PromotionSweepstake < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :promotion
  belongs_to :sweepstake
  before_destroy :check_for_promotion_on_destroy

private

  def check_for_promotion_on_destroy
    raise 'deleting the last sweepstake' if promotion.sweepstakes.count == 1
  end
end

class Sweepstake < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :promotion_sweepstakes
  has_many :promotions, :through => :promotion_sweepstakes
  before_destroy :check_for_promotions_on_destroy

private

  def check_for_promotions_on_destroy
    promotions.each do |prom|
      raise 'deleting the last sweepstake' if prom.sweepstakes.count == 1
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Adding a before_destroy method to PromotionSweepstake was one of my attempts too, but somehow I must have gotten that method wrong (it's lost now). I'd be really happy if you could jot it down just so I can see if I completely missed my goal or not. The bounty is yours though (in 14 hours).

Comment: @eml, I've revised the answer. Does it cut it now?

Comment: thanks for that snippet. Sorry for not granting you the bounty earlier, I would have eventually even if you didn't revise your answer. Many thanks to you my friend.